# Provisioning and Configuration - Azure cloud

Tags: azure, jenkins, automation, ansible, aws-cloudformation

For provisioning AWS services(EC2/R53/VPC/S3/..), technology like Terraform have unreliable approach in terms of performing rollback, error handling etc.

AWS CloudFormation templates address these problems.

CloudFormation templates are used for both provisioning of aws services(like EC2/VPC/r53/S3/...) and configuration of every service.

Additionally this template approach should easily fit into [scripted](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline/QA/Prod) pipeline using Jenkins.

---

What is the approach for provisioning and configuration of services in Azure cloud?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview

Answer (score 1):

Its called Azure Resource Manager (Peter gave a helpful link in the comments). You will interact with ARM through Azure powershell, Azure Cli, ARM Templates, different SDK's or just plain rest calls to create resources.

ARM Templates are the closest thing you can get to CloudFormation templates, but they dont really have all the features of CloudFormation templates.

For example, there is no preview of the changes that will happen before you run the template. some services can not be configured with ARM Templates (or some of the properties cannot be configured).